# Draw box with dynamic with x and y position in SAP Script?

Tags: abap, sapscript

I would like to draw a box dynamically in SAP Script, whereas the POSITION YORIGIN for the box will be changing constantly depending on the availability of data for print.

For more Detail , Please have a look on the pic.
On page2 marked area, I want to display data on page3. Empty area on page2 is not fixed and vary depending on the data.Therefore , I have to display page3 data on empty space which is not fixed.

[image: Sap Script page2]

[image: SAP Script Page3]

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: Question already asked multiple times in the SAP forum: 
[How to draw a dynamic box in sapscript?](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/164701), [SAP-Script - Draw Table (Boxes) with variable number of lines](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/108676), 
[Dynamic BOX in sapscript - Archived Discussions and Documents](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/461772), [How to draw dynamic table in SAP Script !](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/124650), etc. If none answers your question, then please give details.

Comment: Question has been asked multiple times for drawing box only. I want to change position of box also which have not been address in sap forum.

Comment: Do you mean that if you have for instance `BOX XPOS 16 CH WIDTH 0 MM HEIGHT 18 MM FRAME 10 TW,` but you want to assign the values at runtime, i.e. instead of XPOS 16, you want something like `XPOS VAR`, where var is a variable set at runtime ?

Comment: I have updated the question, You might get better idea of the question.For my case, POSITION YORIGIN  will be changing depending on the data for print.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the `YORIGIN` value dynamically, however here is one workaround how you can place box in a dynamic way. You can do this from print-program:

```
DATA: command TYPE c LENGTH 100.

command = 'BOX WIDTH ''17.5'' CM HEIGHT 5 CM FRAME 10 TW INTENSITY 15'.

CALL FUNCTION 'CONTROL_FORM'
 EXPORTING
  COMMAND = command
  EXCEPTIONS
  UNOPENED = 1
  UNSTARTED = 2
  OTHERS = 3.
```

This will insert new box on the form, and you can control the position by changing `command` string conditionally depending on the presence of data on page 2.